# npm throwing error whenever i try to install some new npm package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I was working on this React project and from the beginning I am getting these but I ignored them all and used `npm i package_name -f` to install and surely do this command do the job but I want to know what things are causing the issue and I want to know how to fix all these issues. Please don't suggest doing `npm audit fix --force`, I have already done that.

Here are the errors that I am getting:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-currency-format@1.1.0     
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from
 @mui/material@5.10.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.10.2
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.10.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.10.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.10.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.10.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.10.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.10.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/styled-engine@5.10.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/styled-engine
npm ERR!       @mui/styled-engine@"^5.10.2" from @mui/system@5.10.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/system
npm ERR!         @mui/system@"^5.10.2" from @mui/material@5.10.2
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/system, the root project)       
npm ERR!   15 more (@mui/base, @mui/icons-material, @mui/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-currency-format@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-currency-format
npm ERR!   react-currency-format@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2        
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-currency-format@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-currency-format
npm ERR!     react-currency-format@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry   
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps 
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm ERR! While resolving: react-currency-format@1.1.0     
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
```

This says you are using `react` v18.2.0. And that the problem is caused by `react-currency-format`

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-currency-format@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-currency-format
npm ERR!   react-currency-format@"^1.1.0" from the root project
```

This error message says `react-currency-format` v1.1.0 is dependent on `react` v15 or v16 or v17 only. So v18 of `react` is not supported by this version.

To solve this, either downgrade `react` to v17 or get a version of `react-currency-format` that supports `react` v18 (if it exists)

Comment: somehow this has done the trick but now new error has occured. Is this normal to have error like this?

Comment: Yes, things like this happen. Learn more by reading up on `Transitive dependencies` and `Peer dependencies`.